# "Error in Loading DLL" when trying to launch the label wizard

Tags: microsoft-access, dll

I am trying to run the label wizard in Microsoft Access 2007, but when I click on **Create** → **Labels**, I get this error message:

[image: Label Wizard: Error in loading DLL]

Comment: Have you run the REPAIR on Office from the ADD/REMOVE PROGRAMS tool in Control Panel?

Comment: Can you update your answer with what you have tried thus far?

Comment: @David W. Fenton - doing a REPAIR seems to fix it . . . if you move your answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual first step in troubleshooting a problem like this (i.e., the functionality of an Office program is not working) is to run the REPAIR function on Office from the ADD/REMOVE PROGRAMS tool in Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the solution was running a 'repair' solved the problem:

1. Control Panel
2. Uninstall a Program
3. Select your office suite
4. Select "Change":

**XP**

[image]

**WIN7**

[image]

Run through the setup process BUT SELECT REPAIR instead.

**For Office 2007 it looks like this:**
[image]

**For Office 2010 it looks like this:**
[image]

If this doesn't work, then you can also try uninstalling and re-installing the program.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one also:

1. Click the Microsoft Office button, and then click "Access Options"
2. In the "Access Options" dialog box, click "Current Database"
3. Under "Application Options", select the "Compact on Close" check box